# Finding distance between two vertices in Graph?

Tags: java, graph

I feel like I've tried a million things and I cannot get my code to run, this is for a rather introductory java class. I am trying to find the distance between two vertices within my graph, which correlates to a DSHashmap, which only takes Strings. Any help would be super appreciated!

```java
            /**
     * Find the distance between two vertices in this graph
     * 
     * The distance between two vertices is the number of edges
     * in a shortest path from one vertex to the other vertex.
     * 
     * @param v The first vertex
     * @param w The second vertex
     * @return the distance between v and w
     */
    public int distance(String v, String w){
        DSHashMap<String> parent = new DSHashMap<>();
        DSHashMap<String> visited = new DSHashMap<>();
        LinkedList<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
        int length = 0;

        q.clear();
        q.add(start);
        visited.put(v, "");
        
        while (!q.isEmpty()){
            String firstofQ = q.removeFirst();
            for (String nbr : graph.get(firstofQ)){
                if (visited.containsKey(nbr)){
                continue;
            }
            q.add(nbr);
            visited.put(nbr, "");
            parent.put(nbr, firstofQ);
        }
        }
    if (parent.size()== 0){
        return 0;
    }
```

I tried going through the hashmap using a breadth first search, and adding whenever the current vertice wasn't the parent or visited.

Comment: what exactly means that you cannot get your code to run? what error are you getting?

Comment: An error occurred:
DSGraph.java:407: error: reached end of file while parsing
    }
     ^
1 error

Comment: where is `DSGraph` coming from? I suppose it's some library. What is your input file that it fails to parse?

Comment: DSGraph is the name of the file Im coding on, and the inout file is the grader the assignment is using, if works with all other problems besides this.

Comment: so I assume that you have a problem somewhere outside the code you shared. `DSHashMap` is also your implementation of a `HashMap`?